# Python read a csv file and map it to an object directly

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to parse some data for my project.
I have following structure:

```
class Subject:
     #listing the fields only
     subject_name
     grade
     prof_name
     details
     (few more )
     
class Student:
     #listing the fields only
     name
     subjects = [] --------> imp
```

I am going to get a comma separated csv file as input to the program which is going to look like

```
subject_name,grade, details, prof_name...(5-6 fields)
maths,A,maths-101,abc
science,C,science-101,def
...
```

Is there a tool in Python that will help me map this file directly on the subject class and create a list(array) and return?
Something like:

```
Subjects subjects = readfile(subjects.txt)
```

If not then can something return me a JSON / dict that I can map directly to subjects?
OR is there a completely different yet better way of doing this?
(I cannot use DB need to stick with csv for assignment)

any help is appreciated?

Comment: Look into pandas library, you can read csv file and use to_json method on created dataframe. Then you use that dictionary to create clasess

Comment: Check out setting `__dict__` on your class instance

Comment: Read each row in the csv file, and create a new `Subject` class instance with those column values.  What is the difficulty?